# Is it possible to assign two content properties to a single pseudo-element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I am using the following code below to place a black bar at the top and bottom of an image (cutting off part of the image with the black bar). I am using a `::before` pseudo-element to create the top bar and an `::after` pseudo-element to create the bottom one.

It seems unnecessary (and messy) to have to create two css rules to achieve single effect on a single image. I would like to know whether it is possible to create this effect in one go such as by creating two content properties, as in the title, or any other way other than the way I have currently implemented it. Any comment would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```js
var kittenimg = document.querySelectorAll('img');
if (kittenimg.length > 0) {
  kittenimg.forEach(function(image) {
    image.outerHTML = '<div class="kitten-image">' + image.outerHTML + '</div>';
  });
}
```

```css
.kitten-image {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.kitten-image:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  padding: 0px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.kitten-image:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  padding: 0px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/287" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/408/287" />
</div>
```

Comment: .kitten-imgage:after, .kitten-imgage:before{ ...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to skip declaring both selectors, but you can simplify your css like this by declaring them together in the beginning and then override one of them right afterwards:

```
.kitten-image:after,
.kitten-image:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.kitten-image:before {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Note: I followed OP's code example (edited out a typo only) but I would prefer to put the black element for :before on top of the image with top: 0 and :after at the bottom, to follow css semantics.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that typo. If I don't get a solution that only requires one rule I will mark this as correct btw.

Answer (score 0):

### **No need of ::before and ::after**.

you can simply use the `border-top` and `border-top` CSS property if you want to have a black bar on top and bottom of the image. Add a classname(.img) to the image tag and u can add border-top and border-bottom.

```
.img{
border-top:60px solid black;
border-bottom:60px solid black;
}
```

```js
var kittenimg = document.querySelectorAll('img');
if (kittenimg.length > 0) {
  kittenimg.forEach(function(image) {
    image.outerHTML = '<div class="kitten-imgage">' + image.outerHTML + '</div>';
  });
}
```

```css
.kitten-imgage {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.img{
border-top:80px solid black;
border-bottom:80px solid black;
height:calc(350px - 160px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="img" src="https://placekitten.com/200/287" />
  <img class="img"  src="https://placekitten.com/408/287" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I am trying to cut off part of the image with the black bar and this implementation does not do that. is it possible to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: check out my answer u can fix height height:calc(350px - 160px); calculate height using calc property. 160px - 80px top border and 80px bottom border and just subtract that. I helps to reduce the size of the image @sample

Comment: I don't understand what height:calc(350px - 160px) did? In my post you cannot see the tail of the cat on the right, which is the desired result, but in yours you can still see the tail.. I am trying to cut off part of the image. Am I wrong?

Comment: yes u right actually you want to crop the image But i am not cropping just reducing the image size. @sample